# speech_recognition and DeepL - try to translator with speech to text

Tags: python, deepl

I am a complete beginner

I am trying to send a text via voice input using DeepL API and see the translation as output.
Speech to text works, but it throws an error when executing the translator.translate_text_deepl().

main.py

```
import speech_recognition
import translator

recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()

while True:
    try:
        with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
            recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic, duration=0.2)
            audio = recognizer.listen(mic)
            text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="de-DE")

            print(f"Record: {text}")

            translated_text = translator.translate_text_deepl(text, "en")
            print(f"Translated text: {translated_text}")

    except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError():
        recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
        continue
```

translator.py

```
import requests

def translate_text_deepl(text, target_language):
    api_key = "MY_API_Key"
    url = "https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate"
    data = {
        "auth_key": api_key,
        "text": text,
        "target_lang": target_language
    }
    response = requests.post(url, data=data)
    result = response.json()
    return result["translations"][0]["text"]
```

Comment: Could you please share the error you're receiving and a sample input text you're getting the error for? Your `translate_text_deepl` works for me locally with my key, but this doesn't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DeepL offers an [official Python client library](https://pypi.org/project/deepl/), you might find that easier to use. It might resolve the error you get, or give you more information about what is going wrong.

To use it change your translator.py file to:

```
import deepl

def translate_text_deepl(text, target_language):
    translator = deepl.Translator("MY_API_Key")
    return translator.translate_text(text, target_lang=target_language)
```